# Jupyter Pre-Execution Hook / Cell Change Listener

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter, jupyter-lab, jupyter-extensions

I've been exploring different ways to listen for text changes in a notebook cell within JupyterLab. My current approach involves using [INotebookTracker's](https://jupyterlab.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/interfaces/notebook.INotebookTracker.html) `activeCellChanged` and `currentChanged` events to attach an event listener to the `CodeMirror` / `IEditor` instance of the active cell. This approach does work. However, I am looking for a more direct/intended way.

The implementation looks something like this:

```js
notebookTracker.activeCellChanged.connect(() => {
      const cell = notebookTracker.activeCell;
      const editor = cell.editor.editor. 
    
      // Create an update listener extension
      const updateListenerExtension = EditorView.updateListener.of((update: ViewUpdate) => {
        if (update.docChanged) {
          // The document content has changed
          const currentContent = update.view.state.doc.toString();
          console.log('Editor content changed:', currentContent);
        }
      });
  
      // Attatch event listener
      cmEditor.dispatch({
        effects: StateEffect.appendConfig.of(updateListenerExtension)
      });
  
    }
  });
```

As I mentioned, the approach seems hacky, especially `editor.editor`, as it feels like bypassing some layers of abstraction. I’m wondering if there’s a more elegant or intended way to achieve this, potentially through a deeper dive into the `CodeMirror` API?. Any guidance or experience shared in this area would be greatly appreciated.

---

Additionally, I've come across suggestions for a "pre-execution hook" using `NotebookActions.executionScheduled`:

```
NotebookActions.executionScheduled.connect((_, args) => {
  let cell: Cell;
  let notebook: Notebook;
  notebook = args["notebook"];
  cell = args ["cell"];
  // Additional logic here...
});

});
```

However, I'm looking for a solution that works in real-time as the user types, not just upon cell execution.

[Cross Link to Jupyter's discourse](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/seeking-better-approach-to-pre-execution-hook-cell-event-listener/22420)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't have time to write a full answer but you may wish to explore listening to model (`sharedModel`) changes for model associated with given cell/editor.